# Order pairs/triplets of rows given the sum of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to order pairs (or group of 3,4 etc.) of rows given the SUM of a certain value.

The rows are consecutive based on the concatenation of Name+Surname+Age

To better understand given the following table:

```
ID  Name    Surname Age Salary
------------------------------
1   John    Smith   30  2
2   John    Smith   30  10
3   Rick    James   22  300
4   Rick    James   22  1000
5   Rick    James   22  5
6   Mike    Brown   50  200
7   Mike    Brown   50  20
```

I'd like to have a final table that should be ordered DESC by the sum of Salary of each Name+Surname+Age and keeping the rows with same Name+Surname+Age next to each others despite the ID column is different. This would be the expected result:

```
ID  Name    Surname Age Salary
------------------------------
3   Rick    James   22  300
4   Rick    James   22  1000
5   Rick    James   22  5
6   Mike    Brown   50  200
7   Mike    Brown   50  20
1   John    Smith   30  2
2   John    Smith   30  10
```

As you can see the rows with Name+Surname+Age = "Rick Jams 22" are on the top since their total sum would be 1305, followed by "Mike    Brown   50" (sum = 220) and "John   Smith   30" (sum = 12).
Additionally, the number of rows has to be the same in the resulting table.

How can I do that using Oracle SQL?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Storing Age is generally a bad idea, because every day is someone's birthday - and data may become invalid.

Comment: @jarlh: maybe it's the age they were promoted to that salary at.

Comment: Hi, the rows are indicating duplicates which have different id but same Name+Surname+Age. The goal is to understand which are the duplicates related to the highest salary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.*,
        COALESCE(SUM(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY name, surname, age), 0) ss
FROM    mytable t
ORDER BY
        ss DESC
```

Comment: You need to add age as well in the partition

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! 
However I get first all the results that had 0 as Salary (and the new correspondent "ss" column is empty). How can I change that to have those at the bottom of the table? I've tried with 'COALESCE(SUM(salary),0) OVER (PARTITION BY name, surname, age) ss' 
but I get following error:
"Statement 1 is not valid. ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Surname, Age, Salary
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, Surname, Age, Salary,
         SUM(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Surname, Age) AS sum_of_sal
  FROM mytable) t
ORDER BY sum_of_sal DESC, ID
```

The query uses the window version of `SUM` in order to calculate the sum of salaries per `Name, Surname, Age` partition. We can use this field in an outer query to do the sorting.

Comment: No need for a sub query.

Answer (score 1):

or try this

```
  SELECT ID, Name, Surname, Age, Salary         
  FROM mytable
  ORDER BY SUM(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Surname, Age) DESC, ID
```